# 2006 Subaru Impreza Power Door Button

Tags: subaru, power-windows, impreza

So one night after getting home I lifted up on the power window button to close the window - which it did....but the button kept going up and is now loose inside the housing and will no longer operate the window.  It felt/sounded like the plastic clip just snapped/failed.

Can you just replace the button?

Comment: I'd say it's the whole panel in the door you'd have to replace. Go to a wreckers and buy a whole door card for your make, model and year of car, cheaper in the long run. Also, try not to go too He-Man on the poor window switches! :P

Comment: Actually, on that note, push the button back whilst pulling up yet pushing down on the pivot point, if you know what I mean, and see if the window will move. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The plastic hinge areas on the "button" have broken, and there is not fixing that easily.

However, the good news is that such things are readily available on "eBay" (used) if you have such an outlet available, and the process for replacing the "master window switch panel" is not all that complicated.

I'm certain there are youtube videos, perhaps even for your exact car, which would demonstrate the process and make it a nice job if you are willing to accpet the challenge.

That switch should be not more than $30-$50 used.

Good luck!

Comment: plus, that panel switch is very common across all models of Subaru of similar age. If you have a junk yard or car breaker nearby, it's a five minute job to get the switch out.